# How to localize child theme with Loco Translate

Tags: php, wordpress, localization

I am getting my head around adding localizable strings to a wordpress child theme, and have not been able to do this successfully.

I have a child theme with a .php page to which I want to add a localizable string. In my child theme's `functions.php`, I have added the following line:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'i-craft-child', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Next, using Loco Translate, I uploaded the files `de_DE.po` and `de_DE.mo` to the directory `/languages` within the child theme directory.

Finally, I added the following line to my html page:

```
<span><small>><?php _e( 'Your email address is also your username and it cannot be changed', 'i-craft-child' ); ?></small></span>
```

However, the `span` above is displayed in English (instead of German). I am not sure where in the localization process am I failing and would appreciate any pointers to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your theme text-domain is included, you can use something like this (if file doesn't exists, it will break your site, so use it on test environment).

```
$loaded = load_child_theme_textdomain( 'i-craft-child', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

if( ! $loaded ) {  
    echo 'Unable to load files';
    die;
}
```

Also, did you specify `WP_LANG` in `wp-config.php`, like this?

`define('WP_LANG', 'de_DE'); // for example`

Comment: Ok, I'll try that once I get back to my rev machine. Just for clarity, the parent theme also calls the load_theme function (with the i-craft text domain). I suppose the text domain for the child theme is not loaded by the parent, thus the need to add it in the child's functions.php? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind that you should use `load_child_theme_textdomain`  instead.

Comment: The link above says it's invalid.

Comment: Updated, just check in documentation for more details about `load_child_theme_textdomain`.

Comment: The site dies with the code above, which means load_child_theme_textdomain is not return as expected. Does this method ofter access to an error message? My directory /wp-content/themes/i-craft-child/languages does exist and it contains the .po and .mo files.

Comment: Problem solved. I'll detail the answer below, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the pointer from unixarmy above, the problem was that the function `load_child_theme_textdomain` was not able to read the files, due to me using the function `get_template_directory()` as a parameter. `get_template_directory()` will return the path of the parent theme, not the child. Substituting that for `get_stylesheet_directory()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved that problem going to the Advanced configuration inside Loco:

> Themes -> Child Theme Name -> Advanced.

Inside this area you can define the 'text domain' you will use when translating your theme, for example:

`<?php _e('My string','generatepress-child'); ?>`

Where generatepress-child is the text domain.

In my case the child theme and parent theme where merging on the same path (on the parent path) and loco wasn't able to 'fetch / scan' the strings inside the child theme, so I added manually the new child path inside this advanced section and now I can translate the strings inside my child theme.

After this I have had to add this lines on my functions.php parent theme:

```
function wpdocs_child_theme_setup() {
   load_child_theme_textdomain( 'generatepress-child', get_stylesheet_directory()  );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_child_theme_setup' );
```

Hope it helps!